# Cannot install Django using pip

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, pip, python-2.7, django

I'm trying to install Django 1.11 on ubuntu 16.04 using pip (python 2.7)

I ran the following command: `sudo pip install Django` 
but I get:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Copying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769015/1526703) from Stack Overflow:

You need to upgrade pip as follows:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Note: You may need to use `sudo python` above if not in a virtual environment.

(Note that upgrading `pip` using `pip` i.e `pip install --upgrade pip` will also not upgrade it correctly. Its just a chicken-and-egg issue. `pip` wont work unless using TLS >=1.2)

As mentioned in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703), **this is due to the recent TLS deprecation for pip. Python.org sites have [stopped support](https://status.python.org/) for TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1.**

From the Python status page:

> **Completed** - The rolling brownouts are finished, and TLSv1.0 and
>   TLSv1.1 have been disabled. Apr 11, 15:37 UTC

**For Pycharm (virtualenv) users:**

1. Run virtual environment with shell. (replace "./venv/bin/activate" to your own path)

   ```
   source ./venv/bin/activate
   ```
2. Run upgrade

   ```
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
   ```
3. Restart your pycharm, and check your python interpreter in Preference.